# SAS: How to use different symbols for a plot based on a binary variable

Tags: plot, sas

I'm trying to plot a data that looks something like this:

```
Year    Test    Mark
2000    98      0
2001    70      1
2002    80      0
2003    79      0
2004    80      0
2005    75      1
2006    77      1
2007    85      0
2008    90      0
2009    97      0
2010    90      0
2011    98      0
2012    96      0
2013    94      0
```

I would like to plot the year in x axis, test score on the y, be able to join the points together and use different symbols for the binary 'mark' variable: 0 and 1.

Which proc procedure would let me do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'join'?

Comment: Join as in connecting the points @Joe

Comment: So you want two scatterplots, mark=0 and mark=1, with two different marker symbols, and then lines joining consecutive years (2000 line to 2001 line to 2002)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PROC SGPLOT with a data attribute mapping (dattrmap=) data set.  Specific a scatter plot to plot the points and a series plot to connect them.

```
data toPlot;
format Year Test best. Mark 1.;
input Year Test Mark ;
datalines;
2000    98      0
2001    70      1
2002    80      0
2003    79      0
2004    80      0
2005    75      1
2006    77      1
2007    85      0
2008    90      0
2009    97      0
2010    90      0
2011    98      0
2012    96      0
2013    94      0
;;
run;

/*Set the marker attrib (astrisk=0 circle=1)*/
data plotattr;
format ID $8.
       VALUE 1.
       markersymbol markercolor $32.;
input ID VALUE markersymbol $ markercolor $;
datalines;
abc 0 asterisk red
abc 1 circle green
;;
run;

ods html;
proc sgplot data=toPlot dattrmap=plotattr;
series x=year y=test;
scatter x=year y=test / group=mark attrid=abc;
run;
ods html close;
```

Produces this:
[image]